# How to make efficient getters and setters method

Tags: c#

I am trying to get largest from three integers of 5 objects, the code works, but looks kind of bulky and inefficient, is there any way I can improve it? can I also combine one method `getLargest` to compute largest, smallest and average, without using an array?

```
  class Calc
  {
    private int num1, num2, num3, Ans;

    public int ans  { get { return Ans; }  set { Ans = value; } }
    public int Num1 { get { return num1; } set { num1 = value; } }
    public int Num2 { get { return num2; } set { num2 = value; } }
    public int Num3 { get { return num3; } set { num3 = value; } }

    public void getLargest(int x, int y, int z)
    {
         ans=(Math.Max(Math.Max(x, y), z));
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Why do you think this code is inefficient? Too slow? Too large memory footprint?

Comment: Your properties aren't really doing anything, so they can be defined as `public int PropertyName { get; set; }` for simplicity purposes.

Comment: `int Num1 { get;set; }` will create getter and setter automatically. If you just want it to become a property.

Comment: `get largest from three integers of 5 objects` I don't understand this. What are these 5 objects you speak of?

Comment: No one is really touching on your last question, but I'd recommend not combining getLargest into largest, smallest, and average calculations. A method should (ideally) do a single thing. Sometimes that's just unavoidable or impractical, but 3 fundamentally different calculations would be quite unusual and unintuitive.

Comment: [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties) has to have a purpuse.  Example: A `Date` will have a `Month` property. A `Person` a `Name` property. Why would a Calc have 3 numbers properties? Does that mean that a `Calc` with 4 numbers need to be a different Class?

Comment: So you want to get the minimum, maximum and average `Num1` across all 5 instances? And the same for `Num2` and `Num3`?

Comment: I will recommend adding a [mre]. With the input data and the expected output.

Comment: Unambiguous, clear and complete specification of a problem is a necessary prerequisite.

Comment: This question should be posted at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), its exactly what Code Review is intended for - improve code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've specified without using an array, I suppose this is your best option for "cleaner", though I doubt this produces any noticeable speed improvements, is there a reason you don't want to use an array? What's the purpose of the class?

```
class Calc
{

    public int ans { get; set; }

    public int Num1 { get; set; }

    public int Num2 { get; set; }

    public int Num3 { get; set; }

    public void getLargest(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        ans = Math.Max(Math.Max(x, y), z);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can make this a lot smaller...

```
public class Calc
{
    public int Max => Math.Max(Math.Max(Num1, Num2), Num3);
    public int Min => Math.Min(Math.Min(Num1, Num2), Num3);
    public int Avg => (Num1 + Num2 + Num3) / 3;
    public int Num1 { get; set; }
    public int Num2 { get; set; }
    public int Num3 { get; set; }
}
```

(This requires `using System.Linq;` at the top)

What this does is creates auto-properties (properties with no bodies) which automatically creates the backing fields for you.

Technically this is a little more inefficient as it will calculate them every time, so what you would want to do is something more like this:

```
public class Calc
{
    public int Num1 { get; private set; }
    public int Num2 { get; private set; }
    public int Num3 { get; private set; }
    public int Max { get; private set; }
    public int Min { get; private set; }
    public int Avg { get; private set; }

    public Calc(int num1, int num2, int num3)
    {
        Num1 = num1;
        Num2 = num2;
        Num3 = num3;
        Max = Math.Max(Math.Max(Num1, Num2), Num3);
        Min = Math.Min(Math.Min(Num1, Num2), Num3);
        Avg = (Num1 + Num2 + Num3) / 3;
    }
}
```

(There are different ways to construct this object, the above is just an easy-to-understand method of doing so). This will "cache" the results in an immutable object (which is something you want to learn about).

Comment: His method getLargest doesn't utilsie Num1, Num2 and Num3, it takes x, y and z, so we can only assume that your solution produces different results to the intended results. He also for some reason specifies not to use arrays

Comment: I didn't see the array part, but I assume that his original code was an error in the "x,y,z" part. I'll fix that other issue.

Comment: This code is indeed a tiny bit less efficient than what is written above, in that in your code, the maximum number is computed every time the `Answer` property is read from, whereas in the OP's code, it is computed only when `getLargest` is invoked and `Ans` can then be read from without any recomputation. In practice, of course, totally negligible for three numbers.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Yes, negligibly affect it for such a small object but I added an immutable example for a more "optimized" solution.